# WIX - change dialog text label from background immediate custom action

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I have defined custom action to scan lan network computers. This action is declared as immediate and triggered after user click dialog button:

```
<CustomAction Id="actionGetNetworkComputers" BinaryKey="actionBinary" DllEntry="GetNetworkComputers" Execute="immediate" Return="check"/>
```

Custiom action code:

```
public static ActionResult GetNetworkComputers(Session session)
{
    ListNetworkComputers.NetworkBrowser nb = new ListNetworkComputers.NetworkBrowser(); 
    Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.View lView = session.Database.OpenView("DELETE FROM ComboBox WHERE ComboBox.Property='SERVER_LIST'");
    lView.Execute();

    lView = session.Database.OpenView("SELECT * FROM ComboBox");
    lView.Execute();
    int Index = 1;

    try
    {
        foreach (string s in nb.getNetworkComputers())
        {
            Record lRecord = session.Database.CreateRecord(4);

            lRecord.SetString(1, "SERVER_LIST");
            lRecord.SetInteger(2, Index);
            lRecord.SetString(3, s);
            lRecord.SetString(4, s);
            lView.Modify(ViewModifyMode.InsertTemporary, lRecord);
            ++Index;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        session.Log(ex.StackTrace);
    }
    lView.Close();


    return ActionResult.Success;       
}
```

There are 2 main problems with this:

Action is blocking, so installer window freezes until nb.getNetworkComputers reurns. If I declare action return as asyncWait, action is executed but retrieved values are not inserted to ComboBox. Also, I need some label indicating operation progress, for example: "Scanning network, please wait" and hide this label after scan ends.

Is this possible with wix? Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to go about this is to schedule the CA is Sync Check exit code and have your CA display it's own modal dialog with a cancel button telling you that a scan is in progress.  Then use a BackgroundProcess class to spin your scan while checking to see if cancel was selected.  When done ( for real or cancelled ) set a property for state and return sucess.

Then in your MSI Control Events you can check that property and either disallow transition to the next dialog or allow it  ( mutually exclusive control event conditions ) based on your business rules.

Comment: Do you mean spawn dialog invoked from custom action? I'm not sure how to display spawn dialog from custom action, also I'm not sure how to use BackgroundProcess class. Should I move network scanning stuff to background thread and exit thread afer user click cancel button? I know how to do this using winforms window, but I have no idea how to use wix spawn dialog in this case. Can you explain it a little more?

Comment: No, in this case I'm actually saying to handle the UI in .NET. Your first dialog will call DoAction YourCustomAction and your Custom Action will throw up a foreground modal dialog displaying progress and allowing cancel while allowing for cancelling of the operation.   I find background process easy to use but if you know how to do it another way using threading that's fine also.

Comment: Ok, but as I know (correct me if I'm wrong), only way to display modal dialog during wix installation process is to use spawn dialog. Any kind of gui created directly using .net stuff  (winformms for example) will be always modeless and it can even appear below installer window - this is not acceptable. So - to be clear: do you mean I should invoke standard .net dialog (winforms window) or some kind wix/msi dialog? In the first case - it seems to be impossible to make it modal, in the second case, I have no idea how to use that kind of dialog to interrupt my network scan thread

Comment: Or I'm fairly certain there is some way to create a modal dialog in .NET and make sure you bring it to the foreground.  You might have to P/Invoke or something but it can be done.  When the form loads it fires off your background process on a different thread and waits for it to return.  At the same time you can press the cancel button and send a message to the background process to terminate the background worker thread and then exit the form.  At that point your CA returns control back to MSI.   This can be done, you just might have to work on your .NET chops.

Comment: Are you sure? Even if I bring to top winforms window created inside custom action, this is still wrong way, because .net window need parent to be modal (parent window handle). In the way you say about, it will still be possible to click to installer window and make my window inactive (not hidden if it has "always on top" flag, but inactive) because this is not possible to set msi installer window as parent for winforms window. I've already figured it out and wix documentation is clear - they say, that I should use spawn dialogs to display REALLY modal dialogs, integrated with installer ui.